# TelegramBot, real time

Tags: python, telebot

Делаю телеграмм бота на пайтоне(впервые), делаю расписание пар для института. **Как можно соединить бота с реальным временем, чтобы, например, при нажатии кнопки "пара на сегодня" выдало именно нынешний день.** Бота пишу через telegrambotAPI(telebot)

Comment: Библиотека `datetime` в помощь, а конкретно `datetime.date(datetime.now())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime
import calendar


d = datetime.date.today()

day = d.day     #Сегодняшний день
month = d.month #Месяц
year = d.year   #Год

wd = calendar.weekday(year = year, day = day, month = month) #Получаем индекс недели 0 - понедельник 1 - вторник и тд.
wd_day = calendar.day_name[wd]                               #Получаем в виде строки день недели.

print(wd_day) #Вывод для проверки дня недели OUT -> Tuesday Это на 15.03.22

#Список дней недель с соответствующим списком пар.
liste = {'Monday': {'Alchemy', 'Potions'},
        'Tuesday': {'Inscription', 'Life safety fundamentals', 'Math'},
         # ..... и так далее        
        }
#Вывод уроков на нужный день недели
print(liste[f'{wd_day}'])

#OUT -> {'Math', 'Life safety fundamentals', 'Inscription'}
```

Ну и конечно вам нужно будет транспонировать все под `бота`. Думаю проблем не доставит